# CSS h3 text placed on top of an image tag

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building an events app using Rails and currently styling my user profile page. Under 'My Events' I have a code loop which shows an image with two h3 tags showing the event title and date. I want the h3 elements to sit on top of the image. I've done this on the index page but I can't seem to replicate the same for the user profile page. Currently I have the images set up correctly but I can't get the text to sit on top of them.

Here's my view and CSS code -

show.html.erb - users

```
<div class="col-md-7" id="userevents">
<div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">                     
                <h2>My Events</h2> 
            </div>  
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <% @user.events.each do |event| %>

                            <div id="eventblock">
                                <%= link_to (image_tag event.image.url), event %>

                                <h3><%= link_to event.title, event %></h3>
                                <h3><%= link_to event.date.strftime('%A, %d %b %Y'), event %></h3>

                                <% end %>
                            </div>  

                </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS -

```
#userevents {
float: right;
margin: 50px;
height: auto;

}

#eventblock img {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
float: left;
position: relative;
margin: 20px;
}


#eventblock h3 {
position: absolute; 

}
```

Ideally I want the text to sit centrally at the bottom of the image.

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
#eventblock h3 {
   z-index:1;
   left:50%;
   top:50%;
   transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
   margin-right:-50%;
}
```

might also need a z-index:-1 in your #eventblock img as well

Comment: All that has done is bring the text together in the centre of the panel-body. the z-index -1 for the img doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I figures it out - turns out I wasn't using the same styling rules as the index page. Here's the amended code.

show.html.erb -

```
<ul>
                        <% @user.events.each do |event| %>

                        <li class="events" id="eventblock"> 
                                <%= link_to (image_tag event.image.url), event %>
                            <div class="text">
                                <h3><%= link_to event.title, event %></h3>
                                <h3><%= link_to event.date.strftime('%A, %d %b %Y'), event %></h3>
                        </li>
                                <% end %>
                            </div>
                    </ul>
```

events.css.scss -

```
li.events { 
width: 350px; 
height: 350px; 
float: left;
margin: 20px;
list-style-type: none;
position: relative; 

}

li.events img { 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
border-radius: 25px;



   }

  div.text  { 

background: transparent; 
padding: 25px; 
position: absolute; 
bottom: 15px;
left: 25px; 

 }

#eventblock {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
margin: 10px;
 }
```